Movie about a woman whose brother dies in war
Please help me remember which movie this is:

The main character, a woman, her brother dies in a war
Her brother's war buddy comes back and pursues her
She has a husband and son, and her husband was a police officer
Her husband dies saving her son
The movie was in color, from 2011 (maybe 2010 or 2012) I think.

Does that ring any bells?

You need a lot more information or this question is going to be closed very quickly. These could help: what time period was it released? Was it colour or black and white? Who is "her" and "she"? What language was it released in? Any more information about the movie would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, I'm new.  My apologies for the vagueness, but I can only remember some details.

Is the war buddy also her later husband? Which war? Was it a movie with big name stars?

You're looking for The Lucky One

Logan is a marine serving in Iraq. While there, he finds a photo of a girl with "keep safe" written on the back. He is admiring it when his unit is attacked. He survives and credits the photo for saving him. He tries to find the owner but can't, assuming he was killed.
When he goes back to the States, he finds it difficult to adjust and is still haunted by what happened. Analyzing the photo, he finds in the background a landmark that tells him she is in Louisiana. He then goes there and finds her. 
He learns her name is Beth. He tries to tell her what happened but can't get the words out. She assumes he's there to apply for the job they advertised looking for someone to help at her family's business, a dog kennel. He says yes but at first she gets an uneasy feeling from him but her grandmother decides to give him a chance.
It isn't long that he makes a connection with her son. He then discovers that it was her brother who had the picture only he doesn't remember him. He sees that her brother's death has a profound effect on her. Eventually they get close which makes her grandmother happy but not her ex who is a deputy sheriff who's always threatening to take their son away from her.





Yes, that's it!  Thank you very much!

Not a problem, glad I could help!
